# How to add object to a list which contains another list

Tags: c#, .net

the problem is , I want to achieve the structure like this:

Category > SubCategory > Product

the scenario will be like , multiple products will be added to sub category, and multiple sub categories will be added to category. I am having very less knowledge, so my question is can we do that, if yes the please help me to achieve that.

Here is my Code:

```
Category obj = new Category();
            obj.CategoryId = categoryId++;
            obj.CategoryName = Console.ReadLine();

            do{
                Console.WriteLine("want to add SubCategory ----(Y/N)");
                string loop = Console.ReadLine();

                if (loop == "Y" || loop == "y")
                {
                    List<SubCategory> subcategories = new List<SubCategory>();
                    SubCategory sub = new SubCategory();

                    sub.CategoryId = obj.CategoryId;
                    sub.SubCategoryId = subcategoryId++;
                    sub.SubCategoryName = Console.ReadLine();
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("want to add product ----(Y/N)");
                        string loop1 = Console.ReadLine();

                        if (loop1 == "y" || loop == "Y")
                        {

                            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
                            Product product = new Product();
                            Product product1 = new Product();
                            Console.Write("Name :");
                            product.ProdictId = productId++;
                            product.ProdictName = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Write("Price :");
                            product.ProductPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                            product.SubCategoryId = sub.SubCategoryId;

                            sub.Products.Add(product);
                        }
                        else { break; }
                        sub.Products.Add(pro)
                    } while (true);


                    obj.SubCategories.Add(sub);
                }
                else { break; }

            } while (true);
            categories.Add(obj); 
        }
```

P.S. here categoryId, SubCategoryId, and ProductId is set as auto-increment.

How can i add multiple products to Subcategory, and multiple sub category to category.

it will be a big help. thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Is it going to be console application only?

Comment: I'm seriously questioning this loop logic, and you haven't specified an actual problem, but I do notice that your second "if loop statement" is checking two different loop variables, when I presume you want to check the same variable for both upper and lower case Y.

Comment: I Understand until `Product product1 = new Product();`
I don't know why you define this, even you didn't even use it.

Comment: sub.Products.Add(product); this statement shows null reference exception. yes it is a console application only  @chetan

Comment: the actual problem is i am not able to add products to subcategory, it shoots null reference exception. and the loop logic is working fine right now @AndyArndt

Comment: I was testing few things, it is useless, forgot to remove that. @GBursali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SubCategory sub = new SubCategory(){Products = new List<Product>()};
```

instead of

```
SubCategory sub = new SubCategory();
```

And

```
Category obj = new Category(){SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>()};
```

instead of

```
Category obj = new Category();
```

And Delete these

```
 List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
 List<SubCategory> subcategories = new List<SubCategory>();
```

You should define the subcategories and products, not an different variable, on your class's variables. Nullexception thrown because it couldn't see any list in your obj class, (you have them but not in you class).

Comment: got it. your solution worked like a charm. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that the collection properties such as `SubCategories` property of object of `Category` class and `Products` property of object of class `SubCategory` are not initialized properly.

Make following changes to your code.

Initialize SubCategories properties of obj as following.

```
Category obj = new Category();
obj.SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>(); // Add this new line to your code
```

Change following line

```
if (loop1 == "y" || loop == "Y")
```

to

```
if (loop1 == "y" || loop1 == "Y")
```

Initialize `Products` property of Subcategory as following.

```
SubCategory sub = new SubCategory();
sub.Products = new List<Product>(); //Add this new line to your code.
```

Remove following lines from the code.

```
List<SubCategory> subcategories = new List<SubCategory>();
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
Product product1 = new Product();
sub.Products.Add(pro)
```

The final version of your code should look as following.

```
Category obj = new Category();
obj.SubCategories = new List<SubCategory>();
int categoryId = 0;
obj.CategoryId = categoryId++;
Console.Write("Enter Category Name : ");
obj.CategoryName = Console.ReadLine();

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("want to add SubCategory ----(Y/N)");
    string loop = Console.ReadLine();
    if (loop == "Y" || loop == "y")
    {
        SubCategory sub = new SubCategory();
        sub.Products = new List<Product>();
        sub.CategoryId = obj.CategoryId;
        sub.SubCategoryId = subcategoryId++;
        Console.Write("EnterSub Category Name : ");
        sub.SubCategoryName = Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("want to add product ----(Y/N)");
            string loop1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if(loop1 == "y" || loop1 == "Y")
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                Console.Write("Name :");
                product.ProductId = productId++;
                product.ProdictName = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Price :");
                product.ProductPrice = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                product.SubCategoryId = sub.SubCategoryId;
                sub.Products.Add(product);
            }
            else { break; }

        } while (true);
        obj.SubCategories.Add(sub);
    }
    else { break; }
} while (true);

categories.Add(obj);
```

This will resolve all your issues.

Comment: the problem was i was not able to add product data to subcategories. got your point thanks.